# fibonacci sequencing difficulties in python

Tags: python, fibonacci

(I'm in a basic computer science class, and this is homework)

I am trying to create a basic  fibonacci sequence with "n" as the parameter.

what I have so far seems to be working fine when I run the program in idle

```
def fibonacci(n):
    a=0
    b=1
    n = input("How high do you want to go? If you want to go forever, put 4ever.")
    print(1)
    while stopNumber=="4ever" or int(stopNumber) > a+b:
       a, b = b, a+b
       print(b)
fibonacci(n)
```

but when I try to run the program so that it displays the info I get this error

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:/Users/Joseph/Desktop/hope.py", line 10, in <module> fibonacci(n)
 NameError: name 'n' is not defined
```

Any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: If you created function like this, it shouldn't have any parameters, because you get them inside function from standard input. Deleting `n` would solve this error, however, there would be other errors and your algorithm is also wrong

Comment: @JosephMcMurray: The algorithm isn't wrong.

Comment: @MaciejBaranowski: His algorithm isn't incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `fibonacci` function is taking an input there isn't exactly a need to pass a parameter. But in the case of your error `n` isn't defined in the global scope. I would just get rid of the `n` parameter. Also, just replace `stopNumber` with `n`.

```
def fibonacci():
    a=0
    b=1
    n = input("How high do you want to go? If you want to go forever, put 4ever.")
    print(1)
    while n == "4ever" or int(n) > a+b:
       a, b = b, a+b
       print(b)

fibonacci()
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't pass an `n` you haven't read from the user when you invoke `fibonacci`. Also, you're using `stopNumber` (not `n`). I think you wanted

```
def fibonacci():
    a=0
    b=1
    stopNumber = input("How high do you want to go? " +
        "If you want to go forever, put 4ever.")
    print(1)
    while stopNumber=="4ever" or int(stopNumber) > a+b:
       a, b = b, a+b
       print(b)

fibonacci()
```